# How to make product ratings required in Magento 2.1.2

Tags: magento2, form-validation, ratings

For some reason the star ratings are not being validated on the product page (**Product Review**). The other 3 fields are being validated correctly (Nickname, Summary, & Review).

Has anyone encountered the same issue? The files I have been looking into are:

> shop/vendor/magento/module-review/view/frontend/templates/form.phtml
>   shop/vendor/magento/module-review/view/frontend/web/js/error-placement.js

In the **error-placement** file it does not look like the rating elements are being returned for validation. Only the other 3 as specified above.

[image]

Comment: ever find a solution to this?

Comment: I ended up just default checking one of the rating stars in `form.phtml`